# What bitcoin clients provide GUI support for "BIP 125 Opt-in Full Replace-by-Fee Signaling"?

Tags: transactions

What bitcoin clients provide GUI support for "BIP 125 Opt-in Full Replace-by-Fee Signaling"?  If there are no GUI bitcoin clients that support it are there supported command line bitcoin clients?